# How to fix: Expected 2 output but got 0 on PASTA when submitting Python codes

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing some codes for search algorithms using Python 3. The codes return the expected strings on pc (using command prompt + Edstem) but once test on PASTA, "Incorrect number of lines of output. Expected 2 but got 0." error pops up.

What could be the problem? Why is the codes only returning strings on pc but not on PASTA?

I have tried to check for extra space, comma, empty line but none of them was the problem caused the error.

def main():

```
# Parse in the command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('search_algorithm')
parser.add_argument('input_file')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Parse in the input file
with open(args.input_file, 'r') as input_file:

    content = input_file.readlines()

    for i in range(0,len(input_file.readlines())):
        content[i].strip('\n')

start_node  = int(content[0])
end_node    = int(content[1])

if len(content) == 3:

    # there are forbidden states, insert them in a list
    forbidden_states = list(content[2].split(','))
    if forbidden_states == '\n':
        forbidden_states = []
    else:
        for num in range(0,len(forbidden_states)):
            forbidden_states[num] = int(forbidden_states[num])

else:
    forbidden_states = []
# Create a ThreeDigits object
threeDigitsSolver = ThreeDigits(args.search_algorithm, start_node, end_node, forbidden_states)
# Call solve to get a string with the search path and visited states, then print 
print(threeDigitsSolver.solve())
```

if *name* == '*main*':
    main()

solve() method returns 2 strings, 1 on each line. Tested and worked on command prompt but PASTA received no output.